# Why it shows "404 page not found" when I click the link in my github pages?

Tags: github, markdown, github-pages

I didn't find useful answer for my question.

I added a file into a new folder that I built on my local git, and I type the link of the file using markdown syntax on my github pages posts section, and then I saved it and pushed it. But when I clicked the link in github, it shows "404 page not found"... But I checked my syntax and other info again and again, they are all correct...I don't know what happened!

Answer (score 1):

After publishing your website wait for 10 to 15 min and then click on link it will open.